# Relationship between Mean Value Theorem and the maximum norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am seeking assistance with the following application of the Mean Value Theorem:

Let $x \in \Omega$ and construct an associated neighbourhood $N_x = (a, a+ \sqrt{\epsilon})$, such that $x \in N_x$ and $N_x \subset \Omega$. Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, for some $y \in\overline{N}_x $,

$$ \frac{u(a + \sqrt{\epsilon}) - u(a)}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} = u'(y)...........(1) $$

It follows that

$$ |u'(y)| \le 2\epsilon^{-1/2}||u||_{N_x}  \le C\epsilon^{-1/2}............(2)$$

My problem is that I do not quite follow how expression (2) is obtained from expression (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|_{N_x}}$
\begin{align*}
  \abs{u'(y)} &= \abs{\frac{u(a+ \sqrt \epsilon) - u(a)}{\sqrt \epsilon}}\\
         &\le \epsilon^{-1/2} \cdot \bigl(\abs{u(a + \sqrt \epsilon)} + \abs{u(a)}\bigr)\\
         &\le \epsilon^{-1/2} \cdot \bigl( \norm u + \norm u\bigr)\\
         &= 2 \epsilon^{-1/2} \norm u.
\end{align*}

Comment: much appreciated